# How to quick search then update/delete row if found

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing the code that.

```
Sub DeleteProjectDuplicate()
    Dim BaseWorkbook As Workbook
    Set BaseWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i, j As Long
    Dim needDelete As Boolean
    i = 4
        Do While BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(i, 10).Value <> ""
            needDelete = False
                For j = 3 To i - 1
                    If BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(i, 10).Value = BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(j, 10).Value Then
                        needDelete = True

                        If BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(i, 7).Value > BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(j, 7).Value Then
                            BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(j, 7).Value = BaseWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Cells(i, 7).Value
                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If needDelete Then
                    BaseWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Info").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                Else
                    i = i + 1
                End If
        Loop
    MsgBox ("Complete")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It work but for the large data it take longtime to process. How can I improve it for better.

Comment: One of the simplest methods is to place all your data into an array first, make changes there, then rewrite your array to the spreadsheet. This way you are not making numerous calls to your worksheet.

Comment: Also, while this wouldn't affect your performance, not sure why you need to `Set BaseWorkbook = ThisWorkbook`, as `ThisWorkbook` never changes - and it's the same amount of characters to type. Seems extremely redundant to me. It would make since to set your worksheet object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, in many cases deleting a lot of data in the worksheet can be "expensive", as in it may take a lot of processing power. This will likely be the most taxing portion of your code.

I made some significant improvements to your code.
Instead of reading the cells directly from the worksheet, I've added the data to a multi dimensional array. We will compare values there instead.

Also, do not delete your rows one at a time; instead, create a special range that tracks the rows to delete, then delete them all at once.

Also, since you are no longer making countless read/writes to your worksheet, you no longer need to worry about the `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation` properties of your application, so I removed those.

Take a look at this, you should see some decent improvements:

```
Sub DeleteProjectDuplicate()

    Dim wsProjectInfo As Worksheet  '<-- No need to set ThisWorkbook, declare the ws instead
    Set wsProjectInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Info")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim i As Long   '<-- no need to use 'j'
    Dim wsDataArr() As Variant, delRng As Range
    wsDataArr = wsProjectInfo.UsedRange.Value   '<-- move your data to an array

    With wsProjectInfo
        For i = 3 To UBound(wsDataArr) - 1
            If wsDataArr(i, 10) = wsDataArr(i + 1, 10) Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Rows(i + 1)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Rows(i + 1))
                End If
                If wsDataArr(i + 1, 7) > wsDataArr(i, 7) Then
                    wsDataArr(i, 7) = wsDataArr(i + 1, 7)   '<-- Write data to array, not ws
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .UsedRange = wsDataArr  '<-- rewrite the worksheet with updated data
    End With

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete '<-- Delete your rows all at once

    MsgBox "Complete"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

As the original post. 
Row i will run from top row to bottom row.
Row J will run from row I to bottom row.

Is there any wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried the code? Because it appears in your code the variable `j` was simply `i - 1`. Since this difference is constant, there is no need for another variable to track it.

Comment: I have try your code.

Sorry.

Row I run from top to bottom.
Row J run from top to Row I-1.

Anyway, thank for suggestion of using array.